# Bootstrap Multiple Dropdown Issue

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I Have made the Multiple Drop-down menus Dynamicly but my issue arrises that only the First dropdown menu populates no matter which button is pushed. I can verify in Chrome Console that the information is different in each button dropdown. I have made this Jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/34739/) as a test and the Issue still occurs.

```
<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="371390773" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-reference="toggle">test 1 button</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="371390773">test1</div>


<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="371116034" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-reference="toggle">test 2 button</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="371116034">test2</div>


<button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="371078302" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" data-reference="parent">test3 button</button>
<div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="371078302">test3</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to wrap the `<button>` and `<div>` inside `<div class="dropdown">`. It should look like the following:

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" ... >test 1 button</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" ... >test1</div>
</div>
```

See [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/dropdowns/#single-button). Here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ot72w8n3/) I've corrected using your original example.

Comment: @JamesGerstenberg If this answer solved your problem, could you mark it as the best answer? I'd greatly appreciate it.